# Push Pull Boost Converter

Tags: dc-dc-converter, buck-boost, push-pull

I made a Push-Pull Buck Converter with Vin 350V and Vout 12V. I am currently trying to make it bidirectional by modifying the circuit, but the output makes no sense.
My schematic:
[image]

The simulation result:
[image]

The code I wrote to get the Transformer, inductor, and resistor values.

```
 # https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_sW_LUEcokI
#Transformer windings and Inductor and Cap sizing
#1. TRANSFORMER
Vin = 345  # after losses
Vout = 16
Ton = 5e-6
Bmax = 220e-3
Aeff = 353e-6  # effective magnetic cross section, from this datasheet. https://www.farnell.com/datasheets/1872305.pdf

Np = (Vin * Ton) / (Bmax * Aeff)
print('Np = ', Np)

Ns = (Vout * Ton) / (Bmax * Aeff)
print('Ns = ', Ns)

#2. INDUCTOR
Freq = 1/20e-6
Ioripp = 10

Lo = (0.05*Vout)/(Freq*Ioripp)
print('Lo = ', Lo)

#3. Capacitor
Co = (60e-6*Ioripp)/0.5
print('Co = ', Co)
```

Comment: Please ask a specific question

Comment: M5 and M6. You're feeding lots of common mode DC into the transformer.

Comment: @OskarSkog but that to maintain the Vgs. I tried using a Bootstrapping circuit but that didn't work.

Comment: @Saagar: Huh? I mean the body diodes.

Comment: @OskarSkog I added the body diode, still had the same result.